# Change the error message for a M2M relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Change the error message for a M2M relation:

I have 2 models, Item and Type:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    types = models.ManyToManyField(Type, related_name='items')


class ItemForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model =Item
        fields = ['types', 'name', 'desc']
```

I get the following validation error:

> Select a valid choice. 0 is not one of the available choices.

I want to change this message. How can be done ?

Comment: Where do you get the error message? Do you have a model form? If so, please post also the relevant code from `forms.py`.

Comment: @cezar I added the form; the error I get on submit

Comment: One more question: is your relation optional? Does an object `Item` has to have at least one `Type`, or is it possible to have an `Item` that is not assigned a `Type`?

Comment: @cezar - is not optional

Comment: show your template

Answer (score 2):

In Django forms you can *clean* the user input. For this purpose you can define a method starting with `clean_` and ending with the field name. In your case you could extend the form class like this:

```
class  ItemForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model =Item
        fields = ['types', 'name', 'desc']

    def clean_types(self):
        types = self.cleaned_data['types']
        # now apply logic to check types
        # this is just an example you might need to change
        if types == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please select valid choices for types')
        # modify the validation error as you please
        return types
```

For extensive information on forms and field validation please check the official Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/forms/validation/).

Comment: I know, I used clean_types but Django ignores it, don't call the method. I try to debug and also add 'print' inside